# JAVA Changing volume with JSlider

Tags: java, audio, volume

I have problem with a simple application which can change volume in windows. I found some code's sources on the Internet and after my modifications it works, but only on my PC. It's because my code is not general because I refer to a specific array with which is volume control working. I have to create code in general. This **AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();**  create's me an array of mixers. How can I find ou which of these arrays is for computer's speakers?

Here is code:

```
public void volumecontrol(){
javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.Info[] mixers = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    Mixer.Info mixerInfo = mixers[4];
    Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo);
    Line.Info[] lineinfos = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();

        try {
            Line line = mixer.getLine(lineinfos[0]);
            line.open();
            if(line.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME)){
                control = (FloatControl) line.getControl(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME);

                control.setValue((float) 0.7);
                int value = (int) (control.getValue()*100);                          

                slider = new JSlider((int)control.getMinimum()*100,(int)control.getMaximum()*100, value);
                slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
                slider.setPaintLabels(true);
                System.out.println("Volume:"+control.getValue());                     

                j.add(slider);
                j.pack();
            }
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                control.setValue(slider.getValue()/100f);

            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks for answers!